# How to translate “Steel your heart”?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, idiom, phrase-request

Title says it all — in a moment of despair if you want to inspire someone and say “Steel your heart” how would you do so in German?

I stepped upon this in the sentence

> “Steel your heart and your soul will shine brighter than a thousand suns.”

One attempt to find a decent translation was

> “Stähle dein Herz und deine Seele wird heller scheinen als tausende Sonnen.”

Comment: Asking for a German proverb analogue to an English (or other language) counterpart **is not off topic**. It is not the "translation request" we had excluded per our FAQ. We do have many at times even highly rated examples of such. It will however help people considerably to give you a good answer if we had a bit more context, an example of usage, or an own suggestion. Consider to [edit] your question to add any of these. You may also have a look at other questions tagged [tag:idioms] to see how better received question had done it if in doubt.

Comment: You should include in the question an explanation, what the phrase means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rough equivalents I remember are:

- Fasse Dir ein Herz
- Nimm Dein Herz in die Hand

Comment: +1 für "Fasse dir ein Herz"

Answer (score 1):

Most likely

> Lass den Kopf nicht hängen!

sometimes in combination with

> Halte die Ohren steif.